# Download JSON file from S3 in Server Side

Tags: node.js, amazon-s3

I am considering using **S3** for backend persistent storge.
However, depending on architecture choices, I provide **Get** endpoint to the frontend using **lambda** and **nodeJS** to access JSON file data in s3 **(25 kB size)**, but I have some performance issues when I use

```
//700 ms 
console.time()
const s3 =new S3();
const object= await s3.getObject(sourse).promise
console.endTime()
```

I don't use **CloudFront** because of the cache. I have to modify JSON on the server-side before send back to the frontend so I can't use presigned url.
Any advice to improve reading JSON files from s3 on the server side.

Comment: That sample code should take very little time to run since it just creates a S3 object, and then calls a method that doesn't exist.

Comment: @AnonCoward thanks for a response it takes between 400 to 700 ms to download a file from s3.